# Codeigniter 4 Product Multiple İmage Upload

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

I need to upload images before adding the product in my project, but I couldn't get out of it. Since pictures will be added before the product is added, I do not know how to define the product number on the picture. I am waiting for your help in this regard.

Adding products and uploading images

```
$PostData = [
        'id'              => $this->request->getVar('id'),
        'name'            => $this->request->getVar('name'),
        'description'     => $this->request->getVar('description'),
        'options'         => $this->request->getVar('options'),
        'product_options' => $this->request->getVar('product_options'),
        'seo_tags'        => $this->request->getVar('seo_tags'),
        'price_purchase'  => $this->request->getVar('price_purchase'),
        'price'           => $this->request->getVar('price'),
        'price_discount'  => $this->request->getVar('price_discount'),
        'discount_date'   => $this->request->getVar('discount_date'),
        'tax_rate'        => $this->request->getVar('tax_rate'),
        'unit'            => $this->request->getVar('unit'),
        'free_shipping'   => $this->request->getVar('free_shipping'),
        'images'=>$this->request->getFileMultiple('files')
    ];

    if ($this->request->getFileMultiple('files')) {

        foreach($this->request->getFileMultiple('files') as $file)
        {   

           $file->move(WRITEPATH . 'uploads');

         $data = [
           'name' =>  $file->getClientName(),
           'type'  => $file->getClientMimeType()
         ];

         
        }
      
   }

   


    if ($id) {
        if (!$this->model->find($id)) {
            return $this->respond(['message' => "Ürün bulunamadı"], 400);
        }

        if (!$this->model->update($id, $PostData)) {
            return $this->respond(['message' => "Ürün güncellenirken hata oluştu lütfen sonra tekrar deneyin"], 400);
        }

        return $this->response->setStatusCode(200);
    }

    if (!$this->model->insert($PostData)) {
        return $this->respond(['message' => "Ürün güncellenirken hata oluştu lütfen sonra tekrar deneyin"], 400);
    }

    return $this->response->setStatusCode(200);
```

Comment: what exactly is the problem? if you're labeling your FILE input fields then you can pass along references through that (to link up with the appropriate product). Your question is unclear to me

Comment: *I need to upload images before adding the product*, well then the product needs to be related with the image ID, which is not good if you have several images for the same product. So how about doing it the other way around? Add the product first, get the ´$lastid = $this->db->insert_id();´ and use that to identify the image(s)

Comment: Thank you for your comments. As you said normal, I decided to reverse it.